# Story about a boy trying to rescue his brother from sasquatch-like creatures, and slowly begins turning into one

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book, illustrated-story

I read this book back in the 80s when I was a kid.  I believe it was a fantasy/horror style anthology, which contained illustrations.  It may have been a children's book.

One of the stories dealt with a boy that goes into a forest looking for his brother. His brother has been kidnapped(?) by large, sasquatch-like creatures.  The boy tries convincing the creatures to let his brother go, slowly turning into one of them the more time he spends with them.  The creatures finally let his brother go, but he has to stay.